# ADFS SAML prefix ds missing in <KeyInfo>

Tags: c#, adfs, prefix

I wanted to integrated Token Certificate with SAML object coming through ADFS. I can parse [Using C#] every item except value of certification due to KeyInfo format. I think "KeyInfo" is missing 'ds' prefix. I don't know where I am doing mistake.

```html
<samlp:Response ID=\"_00ca83c9-aad0-4210-9174-87ec874c5103\" Version=\"2.0\" xmlns:samlp=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol\">

 <Issuer xmlns=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion\">*******</Issuer><samlp:Status><samlp:StatusCode Value=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success\" /></samlp:Status>
 <Assertion ID=\"_bac09d77-c98e-48f6-bf62-8bbbbd1756d9\" IssueInstant=\"2015-08-19T23:07:32.659Z\" Version=\"2.0\" xmlns=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion\"><Issuer>http://ADFS.*******.com.au/adfs/services/tru</Issuer>
 
 <ds:Signature xmlns:ds=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\">
 <ds:SignedInfo></ds:SignedInfo>
 <ds:SignatureValue>some value</ds:SignatureValue>
 
 <KeyInfo xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\"><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>some value</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></KeyInfo> 
 
 </ds:Signature>
 
 <Attribute Name=\"LastName\"><AttributeValue>FFFF</AttributeValue></Attribute>
 <Attribute Name=\"Username\"><AttributeValue>fdfdgf</AttributeValue></Attribute>
 <Attribute Name=\"VAL6\"><AttributeValue>AAAAA</AttributeValue></Attribute>
 <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant=\"2015-08-19T23:07:32.549Z\"><AuthnContext>
 <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:federation:authentication:windows</AuthnContextClassRef></AuthnContext></AuthnStatement>
 </Assertion>
 </samlp:Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<samlp:Response ID="_00ca83c9-aad0-4210-9174-87ec874c5103" Version="2.0" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
  <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">*******</Issuer>
  <samlp:Status>
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
  </samlp:Status>
  <Assertion ID="_bac09d77-c98e-48f6-bf62-8bbbbd1756d9" IssueInstant="2015-08-19T23:07:32.659Z" Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    <Issuer>http://ADFS.*******.com.au/adfs/services/tru</Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#dsa-sha1"/>
        <ds:Reference URI="http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xhtml1-20000126/">
          <ds:Transforms>
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
          </ds:Transforms>
          <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
          <ds:DigestValue>j6lwx3rvEPO0vKtMup4NbeVu8nk=</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
      </ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:SignatureValue></ds:SignatureValue>
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
          <ds:X509Certificate>MIICXTCCA..</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
    <Attribute Name="LastName">
      <AttributeValue>FFFF</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="Username">
      <AttributeValue>fdfdgf</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Name="VAL6">
      <AttributeValue>AAAAA</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
    <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2015-08-19T23:07:32.549Z">
      <AuthnContext>
        <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:federation:authentication:windows</AuthnContextClassRef>
      </AuthnContext>
    </AuthnStatement>
  </Assertion>
</samlp:Response>​
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I want <KeyInfo> as <ds:KeyInfo> in SAML Object. Do I need to write any code [Working in C#] or There would be any configuration required at ADFS server?

Comment: You should be able to just add the ds to the opening and closing tags.  I copied the KeyInfo from a webpage and forgot to manually add the ds.